# How to process the script in case of any NaN values between the column In python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to process the an script Where i am Trying to find the Months between the column , The script is working fine but whenever any field is blank it Gives an error.

If any NaN values comes in between It must skips and move to Next rows.

How to resolve the error :

Input Data :

```
Month1    Month2     Month_list
Mar2020   Dec2020
Nov2020   Jan2021
NaN       NaN
Sep2020   Feb2021
Oct2020   Dec2020
NaN       NaN
Dec2020   Mar2021
```

**Expected Output:**

Expected output

```
Month1    Month2     Month_list

Mar2020   Sep2020    Mar2020,Apr2020,May2020,Jun2020,Jul2020,Aug2020,Sep2020
Nov2020   Jan2021    Nov2020,Dec2020,Jan2021
NaN       NaN        NaN
Sep2020   Feb2021    Sep2020,Oct2020,Nov2020,Dec2020,Jan2021,Feb2021
Oct2020   Dec2020    Oct2020,Nov2020,Dec2020
NaN       NaN        NaN
Dec2020   Mar2021    Dec2020,Jan2021,Feb2021,Mar2021
```

**Code :**

```
def get_date_list(x):
    return ",".join(
        item.strftime("%b %Y")
        for item in pd.date_range(x['Month1'], x['Month2'], freq="MS")
    )
    
df['Month_list'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_date_list(x), axis=1)
```

**Error: ValueError: Neither `start` nor `end` can be NaT**

Comment: @ThePyGuy - Not working with the suggested Use Case.

Comment: You can mask the rows with `NaN` values.

Comment: @ThePyGuy -  Please sugegst an answer, As i have tried but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, your function needs a if else block:

```
def get_date_list(x):
    if not pd.isna(x['Month1']):
        return ",".join(
        item.strftime("%b %Y")
        for item in pd.date_range(x['Month1'], x['Month2'], freq="MS") 
        )
    return np.nan
df['Month_list'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_date_list(x), axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df)

    Month1   Month2                                         Month_list
0  Mar2020  Dec2020  Mar 2020,Apr 2020,May 2020,Jun 2020,Jul 2020,A...
1  Nov2020  Jan2021                         Nov 2020,Dec 2020,Jan 2021
2      NaN      NaN                                                NaN
3  Sep2020  Feb2021  Sep 2020,Oct 2020,Nov 2020,Dec 2020,Jan 2021,F...
4  Oct2020  Dec2020                         Oct 2020,Nov 2020,Dec 2020
5      NaN      NaN                                                NaN
6  Dec2020  Mar2021                Dec 2020,Jan 2021,Feb 2021,Mar 2021
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude columns with `NaN` vlaues, one way would be like this:

```py
pd.concat([df, df.dropna().apply(lambda x: get_date_list(x), axis=1).to_frame('Months_List')], axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
Out[169]: 
    Month1      Month2                                        Months_List
0  Mar2020     Dec2020  Mar 2020,Apr 2020,May 2020,Jun 2020,Jul 2020,A...
1  Nov2020     Jan2021                         Nov 2020,Dec 2020,Jan 2021
2      NaN         NaN                                                NaN
3  Sep2020     Feb2021  Sep 2020,Oct 2020,Nov 2020,Dec 2020,Jan 2021,F...
4  Oct2020     Dec2020                         Oct 2020,Nov 2020,Dec 2020
5      NaN         NaN                                                NaN
6  Dec2020     Mar2021                Dec 2020,Jan 2021,Feb 2021,Mar 2021
7  Dec2020     Mar2021                Dec 2020,Jan 2021,Feb 2021,Mar 2021
```

Comment: Where i am suppose to add this line of code in the above code.

Comment: Replace last line as `df = pd.concat([df, df.dropna().apply(lambda x: get_date_list(x), axis=1).to_frame('Months_List')], axis=1)`

Comment: I have tried using like this df['Months_List'] = pd.concat([df, df.dropna().apply(lambda x: get_date_list(x), axis=1)], axis=1), But instead of Month list it gives the output in Date format.

Comment: assign result back to `df` not to `df['Months_List']`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["Month_list"] = df.loc[
    df[["Month1", "Month2"]].notna().all(axis=1), ["Month1", "Month2"]
].apply(lambda x: get_date_list(x), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Month1   Month2                                         Month_list
0  Mar2020  Dec2020  Mar 2020,Apr 2020,May 2020,Jun 2020,Jul 2020,A...
1  Nov2020  Jan2021                         Nov 2020,Dec 2020,Jan 2021
2      NaN      NaN                                                NaN
3  Sep2020  Feb2021  Sep 2020,Oct 2020,Nov 2020,Dec 2020,Jan 2021,F...
4  Oct2020  Dec2020                         Oct 2020,Nov 2020,Dec 2020
5      NaN      NaN                                                NaN
6  Dec2020  Mar2021                Dec 2020,Jan 2021,Feb 2021,Mar 2021
```