# How to Skip NaN values while using a Script in Python

Tags: python, pandas

My script gets aborted whenever there is any Null values comes up in between the Month1 & Month2 columns, The script execution gets stuck and rest of the data doesn't gets processed.

The script is working fine but whenever any rows are blank it gives an error.

Need Suggestion how to handle the rows with NaN values.

**Input Data:**

```
Month1    Month2     Month_list
Mar2020   Dec2020
Nov2020   Jan2021
NaN       NaN
Sep2020   Feb2021
Oct2020   Dec2020
NaN       NaN
Dec2020   Mar2021
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Month1    Month2     Month_list

Mar2020   Sep2020    Mar2020,Apr2020,May2020,Jun2020,Jul2020,Aug2020,Sep2020
Nov2020   Jan2021    Nov2020,Dec2020,Jan2021
NaN       NaN        NaN
Sep2020   Feb2021    Sep2020,Oct2020,Nov2020,Dec2020,Jan2021,Feb2021
Oct2020   Dec2020    Oct2020,Nov2020,Dec2020
NaN       NaN        NaN
Dec2020   Mar2021    Dec2020,Jan2021,Feb2021,Mar2021
```

**Script I am using.**

```
def get_date_list(x):
    return ",".join(
        item.strftime("%b %Y")
        for item in pd.date_range(x['Month1'], x['Month2'], freq="MS")
    )
    
df['Month_list'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_date_list(x), axis=1)
```

**Error i am getting while using the above code** : ValueError: Neither start nor end can be NaT

Comment: Why are you posting the same question again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436648/how-to-process-the-script-in-case-of-any-nan-values-between-the-column-in-python/67437045?noredirect=1#comment119197665_67437045

Comment: @ThePyGuy - Have Taken up the sample data from the above Question, Facing the same Issue over here.

Answer (score 0):

You may drop the rows with the Nan Values using below code:

```
df= df.dropna()
df=df.reset_index(drop = True)
```